# Как оформить class из message_handler

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу сделать из message_handlerа класс, но не выходит, даже не понимаю в чём причина так как ошибок никаких нет, просто сообщение в бот не отправляет. Вот так всё работает:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() in ["/lol", "lol"])
def echo1(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "LOL")

bot.polling()
```

А вот так нет, пример одного из вариантов:

```
class MessageHandler:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.handlers = {}

    def handle(self, message):
        command = message.text.lower()
        if command in self.handlers:
            self.handlers[command](message)

    def add_handler(self, commands, func):
        for command in commands:
            self.handlers[command] = func

    def k_handler(self, message):
        print("lol")
    
handler = MessageHandler(bot)
handler.add_handler(["/lol"], handler.k_handler)

bot.polling()
```